Next JS app deployed to AWS AppRunner managed container but cannot write to flat file in container directory
Situation from the title is this and sorry ahead for lack of full code provided due to company restrictions:

Corporate app source code stored on Bitbucket repository - call it Testing

AppRunner instance is created using repository name as landing page and also where all API endpoints must conduct from) - full directory the instance creates has the format of:
/tool-data/apprunner-data/temp/Testing/instances/###############

Backend developers for company AppRunner service implemented CI/CD pipeline with following commands for all Node JS built frameworks - note these cannot be altered at all by the user (me)



npm install

npm test

node server.js --app-name=Testing



Build completes and app is deployed with URL access

server.js code relevant to the problem
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
 
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = parseInt(process.env['APP_ROOT'] || '8082');
const appName = process.env['APP_NAME'] || 'testingApp'
const dataDir = process.env['APP_DATA'] || path.resolve(__dirname, "./public")
const profilesPath = path.resolve(dataDir, "./profiles.json")

const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
 
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();
  server.use(bodyParser.json());
  server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  server.post(`/${appName}/public/profiles.json`, (req, res) => {
    const { name, skills } = req.body
    let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(profilesPath, 'utf-8'))
    const mainUserIdx = data.findIndex(item => (item.name === name))

    let mainUserProfile = data[mainUserIdx]
    let updatedMainUser = {...mainUserProfile}

    // code that does updating from request body //

    data.splice(mainUserIdx, 1, updatedMainUser)
    fs.writeFile(profilesPath, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('Data overwritten')
    })

    res.sendStatus(200)

  }

  server.get(`/${appName}/public/profiles.json`, (req, res) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(profilesPath, 'utf-8'))
    res.status(200).send(data);
  })

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}/${appName}/`)
  })
})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})

component.js that does the POST to write file
import { serverData } from '@/lib/config'

export default function ProfileForm({ profile }) {
    let name = ...
    let skills = ...
    let description = ...

    async function modifyProfile({ refName, refResp, refSkills }) {
        await fetch(`${serverData}/public/profiles.json`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: name,
                skills: skills,
                description: description
            })
        })
        .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw Error('Problem with POST')
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    })

    // more code // 

    return (
        <>
            // component //
        </>
    )
}

config.js
export const serverData = 'https://apprunner.us.comp/testingApp'

PROBLEM
As the folder instance created from App Runner is random in name and is removed upon app deletion, I have to resort to pulling directory name from the instance and concat with the public folder where profiles.json is located.
However, even with this done, data can't be written through POST request and intercepted from Express for actual writing.  I'm not sure why this routing still won't allow writes to the file.  All read/write access is allowed since this was created for sandbox development environment.
I've tried:

Changing the POST URL and fs directory paths to include/exclude public to see if Next post-builds with inclusion/exclusion of the public folder

Putting it profiles.json outside of public folder


But nothing works.  All development environment settings work as expected so can't see why post build and deployment to App Runner can cause so much problems..
Hope you can help me out with this!
